# non-unicode use regex pattern less few letters

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

I understand that, for non-unicode, we use regex pattern `x00-\x1F\x80-\x9F]+$.`
Can we have that regex excluding alphabetical letters`A, C, G, and T`?

Comment: what do you want to match? Only ACGT? or Everything except ACGT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add A, C, G, and T to the negated character class.

```
^[^ACGT\x00-\x1F\x80-\x9F]+$
```

Comment: Actually, no character is matching this

Comment: @AlexKasina are you sure?  `/^[^ACGT\x00-\x1F\x80-\x9F]+$/.test('a')` returns `true` for me